# Lumen authentication always returns in "unauthorized access"

Tags: php, lumen

I am new to Lumen. I am creating API which need to authenticate each user. I have followed all steps which showed in Lumen documentation. But all API's are returning unauthorized as a response, though I provide valid parameters.

In **routes.php** i have added below code,

```
<?php
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->post('user/getprofiledetails', ['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'uses' => 'UserController@getProfileDetails']);
?>
```

In  **authenticate.php**,

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
 */
protected $auth;
/**
 * Create a new middleware instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Auth $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

In **UserController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

use Dingo\Api\Exception\ValidationHttpException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('auth:api');
} 
 public function getProfileDetails($user_type, $username)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        echo "You are a authenticated user";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You are not authorized to login";
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated . Thank You .

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am facing the same issue. Following the documentation, I receive unauthorised for all requests. I might be missing something. I am using Lumen (8.2.4) (Laravel Components ^8.0) and following the latest documentation...